# how to use fgets/fread to read a PIPE

Tags: pipe, fgets, fread

I have two processes A, B and a pipe(my_pipe[2]) between them, I need process A to read the output of process B. In process B, I have `dup2(my_pipe[1], stdout)`; in A, I need to keep reading the output of B and process it line by line.

I want to use `fread/fgets` in A instead of `read`, but `my_pipe[0]` is a file descriptor instead of a *FILE.  How can I use fread/fgets for a pipe?

Answer (score 3):

[Use `fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) (using the POSIX reference since you're already using POSIX file descriptors):

> NAME
>
> ```
> fdopen - associate a stream with a file descriptor
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> [CX] [Option Start] #include <stdio.h>
>
> FILE *fdopen(int fildes, const char *mode); [Option End]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
> The fdopen() function shall associate a stream with a file descriptor.
>
> The mode argument is a character string having one of the following values:
>
> r or rb
>     Open a file for reading.
> w or wb
>     Open a file for writing.
> a or ab
>     Open a file for writing at end-of-file.
> r+ or rb+ or r+b
>     Open a file for update (reading and writing).
> w+ or wb+ or w+b
>     Open a file for update (reading and writing).
> a+ or ab+ or a+b
>     Open a file for update (reading and writing) at end-of-file.
> ```
>
> The meaning of these flags is exactly as specified in fopen(), except that modes beginning with w shall not cause truncation of the file.

For example:

```
FILE *fptr = fdopen( fd, "rb" );
```

Then you can use `fread()` and `fgets()` (among others) on `fptr`.